# how to update an existed data using spingboot and thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

Using Kotlin.
I'm trying to update a User object by:

1. send old user to update page;

```
@GetMapping("/update/{id}")
    fun updateUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") id: Int, model: Model): String {
        val user = userService.findUserByUid(id)
        model.addAttribute("user", user)
        if (user.uid != 1)
            model.addAttribute("allRoles", userService.addUserRole())
        else
            model.addAttribute("allRoles", userService.adminRole())
        return "updateUser"
    }
```

2. change some vars of that user in html page;

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/userManagement/update}" th:object="${user}" method="POST">
        <label>昵称</label>
        <input type ="text" th:field = "*{usernickname}" placeholder="usernickname" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
        <br>
        <label>密码</label>
        <input type ="password" th:field = "*{password}" placeholder="password" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
        <div>
            <label>职位:
                <input type="radio" name="roles"
                       th:each="myRole : ${allRoles}"
                       th:text="${myRole.name()}"
                       th:value="${myRole}"
                       th:field="*{usertype}"
                       th:attr ="checked=${myRole.ordinal()==0?true:false}"
                />
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-update">更新员工</button>
    </form>
```

3. update user data.

```
 @PostMapping(path = ["/update"])
    fun updateEmployee(@ModelAttribute("user") user: User, model: Model): String {
        try {
            user.password = passwordConfig.passwordEncoder().encode(user.password)
            userService.updateUser(user)  
        } catch (ex: RuntimeException) {
            model.addAttribute("error", ex.message)
            if (user.uid != 1)
                model.addAttribute("allRoles", userService.addUserRole())
            else
                model.addAttribute("allRoles", userService.adminRole())
            return "updateUser"
        }
        return "redirect:/userManagement/"
    }
```

The problem is, at phase 3, the user object i recieved have only usernickname, password and role, other vars becomes **null**.

For example, at phase 1, the user object is like{uid=5,username=aaa,usernickname=bbb,password=****,usertype=MANAGER,usergroup=DEFAULT,bugList={}}

and when i changed nickname and password at updateUser page, then push that commit btn, the user object at phase 3 will be{uid=0,username=null,usernickname=ccc,password=*****,usertype=MANAGER,usergroup=null,bugList=null}

it seems like phase 1 didnot run correctly, the user object i want to transmit didnot transmited.

I think it is caused by wrong syntax, but i cannot find how to solve it.

update:
User entity:

```
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var uid = 0

    lateinit var password: String

    lateinit var username: String

    lateinit var usernickname: String

    lateinit var usertype: UserRole

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="groupid")
    lateinit var usergroup: UserGroup

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bid")
    lateinit var bugList: List<Bug>


    constructor(
        password: String,
        username: String,
        usernickname: String,
        usertype: UserRole,
        usergroup: UserGroup
    ) {
        this.password = password
        this.username = username
        this.usernickname = usernickname
        this.usertype = usertype
        this.usergroup = usergroup
    }

    constructor()
}
```

UserRole:

```
enum class UserRole {
    ADMIN, PROGRAMMER, TESTER, MANAGER;

    val roleAuthority: GrantedAuthority
        get() = SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_$name")
}
```

Comment: Greetings! Please add your `User` and `Role` entities or describe a relationship between them (db-related or plain-string roles). If you have `One-to-Many` or `One-to-One` relationship between your entities, you should add logics to rewrite that relation, 'cause there is autogenerated table `users_roles` or any other that is not auto-updated on roles change.

Comment: @p0var ok, i will add these entities